# AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block items

Tags: python, pandas

> AssertionError: Number of manager items must equal union of block
>   items  manager items: 2820, # tot_items: 2821

I use the following code to combine description columns into a text column. This normally works, but I recently added some columns to `lab_tickets_df`. Now it gives the error above

```
cols = [c for c in lab_tickets_df.columns if "description" in c.lower()] 
lab_tickets_df["Text"] = lab_tickets_df[cols].apply(lambda x:\ ' 
                                           '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

The funny thing is, that now after adding some columns, I get the exact same error when I, for example, do:

```
lab_tickets_df.drop(columns = ["0"])
```

and many other operations.

Why do I get this assertionError for so many operations?